# Simple Addition,Subtraction Javascript Function....Why Does This Not Work?

Tags: javascript, function

i am building a simple javascript function and it is not working what am i doing wrong?
here is the code below guys thanks

```
<p>Simple ADD/SUBTRACT Calculator</p>

<input type="text" id="num1"><br> <!-- field for number 1 -->
<input type="text" id="num2"><br> <!-- field for number 2 -->
Enter ADD or SUBTRACT to calculate<br> 
<input type="text" id="opper" value""><br> <!-- field for ADD or SUBTRACT text -->
<button type="submit" onclick="myCalculator(document.GetElementById('num1').value , document.GetElementById('num2').value)">Calculate</button>

<p id="answerspace"></p><!-- field for the answer -->


<script>
function myCalculator(a, b) {
var theOperatr = document.GetElementById('opper').value;

if (theOperatr = "ADD") {
document.GetElementById('answerspace').innerHTML = a + b;
}

else if (theOperatr = "SUBTRACT") {
document.GetElementById('answespace').innerHTML = a - b;
}

else {
document.GetElementById('answerspace').innerHTML = "NOTHING WAS ENTERED";
}

};
</script>
```

Comment: Please post the code, not pictures of code

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please paste your code into the question and then press the "Code Sample" button in the editor to format it instead of posting as a picture.

Comment: ok added it as code guys

Comment: `if (theOperatr = "ADD")` should be `if (theOperatr === "ADD")` or `if (theOperatr == "ADD")`.  Right now, you're assigned the variable to "ADD" in the if statement, you're not comparing.

Comment: @entropic yea i noticed that earlier that made a big difference it was a rookie move once again im green as a blade of grass with JS thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<p>Simple ADD/SUBTRACT Calculator</p>

<input type="number" id="num1">
<br>
<!-- field for number 1 -->
<input type="number" id="num2">
<br>
<!-- field for number 2 -->
Enter ADD or SUBTRACT to calculate
<br>
<input type="text" id="opper" value "">
<br>
<!-- field for ADD or SUBTRACT text -->
<button type="submit" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>

<p id="answerspace"></p>
<!-- field for the answer -->

<script>
  
  function calculate() {

    var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value);
    var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num2').value);

    var operator = document.getElementById('opper').value;

    if (operator === "ADD") {
      document.getElementById('answerspace').innerHTML = num1 + num2;
    } else if (operator === "SUBTRACT") {
      document.getElementById('answerspace').innerHTML = num1 - num2;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('answerspace').innerHTML = "NOTHING WAS ENTERED";
    }
    
  }
  
</script>
```

`document.GetElementById` should be `document.getElementById`.

You should also use input type `number` for numbers

Due to the way you are calling myCalculator you also needed to call `parseInt` on the values.

I have altered your code *slightly* so it's a bit more readable.

Comment: yea thats what fixed it thanks bro i feel dumb now smh...but now instead of adding them as integers its concentating them like strings...is it because the type attribute is text?

Comment: ok now its saying NaN now when i use your code.this stuff is harder then i thought

Comment: oh it was my browser  your code  works as i wanted thanks a million bro

Comment: Fixed with `===` comparison operator

Comment: exactly im just figuring that out? its written the same way as ADD so why is it not working? @entropic

Comment: @GullyBoy see my comment above yours, i left the `=` from your original code, it should be a `===` comparison operator. The code has been updated

Comment: the "r" in "answerspace" for the else if line is missing is that way? cause i fixed the r and it still doesnt work

Comment: Yes, it's now updated. You need to change `operator = "ADD"` to `operator === "ADD"` and the same with subtract